# Create a column based on a substring in R

Tags: r

I want to create a column in a data frame having values "Mobile" and "Desktop" based on Campaign Name in another column, how should I got about doing this ?

For example :

```
Campaign                         Device 
Branded-Desktop-Campaign1        Desktop
Branded-Mobile-Campaign2         Mobile
```

My data frame has around 2000 rows.

Comment: Do you have any patterns in the `Campaign` column?  If it always occurs after the first `-`, then `sub('.*-([^-]+)-.*', '\\1', df1$Campaign)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're dealing with something like:

```
x <- c("Branded-Desktop-Campaign1", "Branded-Mobile-Campaign2")
```

Try:

```
gsub(".*-(.*)-.*", "\\1", x)
## [1] "Desktop" "Mobile"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub`.  We match the pattern one or more characters followed by - (`.*-`), then capture one or more characters that are not a `-` (`[^-]+`) as a group.  In the replacement, we use the backreference.

```
sub('.*-([^-]+)-.*', '\\1', df1$Campaign)
#[1] "Desktop" "Mobile"
```

Or we can use `stri_extract_first` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first_regex(df1$Campaign, '(?<=\\-)\\w+')
#[1] "Desktop" "Mobile"
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun, this is very helpful and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to look for keywords in your Campaing String and use the result to build your "Device" column:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(mobile = grepl("Mobile", Campaign),
           desktop = grepl("Desktop", Campaign),
           Device = ifelse(mobile, "Mobile", "Desktop"))
```

Of course you can put the regex directly into the ifelse function to do it one step.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this was helpful.